# Defining a probability space to maximise a probablity

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that:

```
P[X=2]=0.3
P[X=5]=0.7

P[Y=1]=0.2
P[Y=2]=0.4
P[Y=5]=0.4
```

I need to define $X$ and $Y$ on the same probability space, so that P[X=Y] is maximized.

I know how to define a probability space that works. e.g

```
 {a,b,c,d} where P(a)=0.1, P(b)=0.2, P(c)=0.3 and P(d)=0.4
 Then define
 X(i) = 2 if i = a OR b, X(i) = 5 if i = c OR d
 Y(i) = 1 if i = b, Y(i) = 2 if i = a OR c, Y(i) = 5 if i = d
```

I know $P[X=Y]=P[X=2 and Y=2]+P[X=5 and Y=5]$ but Im not sure how to maximize this. Is it not always the same anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to define the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. That is, we seek $p,q,r,s,t,u$ such that each row and column adds up to the corresponding probability in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& X = 2 & X = 5 & \sum_x \\ \hline
Y = 1 & p & q & 0.2 \\ \hline
Y = 2 & r & s & 0.4 \\ \hline
Y = 5 & t & u & 0.4 \\ \hline
\sum_y & 0.3 & 0.7 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
Observe that we want to maximize $r + u$. Indeed, notice that $r \leq 0.3$ and $u \leq 0.4$. Conveniently enough, these upper bounds can be obtained greedily as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& X = 2 & X = 5 & \sum_x \\ \hline
Y = 1 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\ \hline
Y = 2 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.4 \\ \hline
Y = 5 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ \hline
\sum_y & 0.3 & 0.7 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

---

Thus, for this example, $\Pr[X = Y] = 0.3 + 0.4 = 0.7$, which is best possible. Indeed, this beats your example's probability of $0.1 + 0.4 = 0.5$.

Comment: I understand this, thank you. But how do i then state my probability space from the joint distribution.

Comment: Define our sample space to be $\{P, Q, R, S, T, U\}$ where $\Pr[P] = p, \Pr[Q] = q$, and so on. Then define:
$$
X(I) = \begin{cases}
2 &\text{if } I \in \{P, R, T\} \\
5 &\text{if } I \in \{Q, S, U\}
\end{cases}
$$
and so on.

Comment: Of course, thanks